# TextToSpeech in Android 9.0 has an error or not supported?

Tags: android

I have a project that uses TextToSpeech to serve certain features. 
Everything is fine until I try to run on Android version 9.0. 
It reported an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.setLanguage(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
```

These are the lines I wrote:

```
private void initializeTextToSpeech() {
        mytts= new TextToSpeech(HomeActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status ==0){
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,
                            "There is no TTS engine on your device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }else {
                    int result = mytts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
                    } else {
                        Log.e("TTS", "success !");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And after I changed the condition `status == 0` to become `status! = TextToSpeech.SUCCESS` then it announced that: "There is no TTS engine on your device".
Seems like version 9.0 TTS is not supported?

Comment: Locale loc = new Locale("en");______
int result = mytts.setLanguage(loc.getAvailableLocales());

Comment: @DPrince hmm ... I tried it and nothing changed

Comment: @DPrince obviously method setLanguage() can not applied to Locale[]

Comment: I think this link " https://stackoverflow.com/a/43036364/7832102 " is helpful to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text to speech not working on android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718216/text-to-speech-not-working-on-android-device)